# First attempt in Ruby Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to Ruby and Rspec, and so I happened to found this bit of code:
Here is my Specification:

```
RSpec.describe Surveyor::Answer, '03: Answer validations' do

context "for a free text question" do
  let(:question) { double(Surveyor::Question, type: 'free_text') }

  # NOTE: The rating validations should not apply for 'free_text' questions.
  subject { described_class.new(question: question, value: 'anything') }
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

Here is my Class:

```
module Surveyor
  class Answer
    def initialize(question_answer)
      @question = question_answer[:question]
      @answer = question_answer[:value]
    end

    def question_type
      # I want to check what is the type of question here.
      # 'free_text' or 'rating'
      # if free_text 
      #   print question type
      # else 
      #   do something
    end
end
```

My question is how can I print(puts) the type of question (free_text/rating) in Answer class?

When I tried using `print question_answer[:question]`it only gave me `#<Double Surveyor::Question>`
So I could not use `question_answer[:question][:type]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the type in the constructor simply: `question_answer[:question].type`, or later in object level methods: `@question.type`.

You can't access it like `question_answer[:question][:type]` because the `double` method in the test creates a classic like object rather than a hash.

A tip: when a method accepts parameters as a single hash you can simply name that as `options` or `params` but if you have only 3-4 params, you can use separate variables for params instead of a hash

Comment: Thank you! that really helps a lot. Plus the tips you gave me really useful to simplified parameters name.